# matplotlib: Stretch image to cover the whole figure

Tags: matplotlib, figure

I am quite used to working with matlab and now trying to make the shift matplotlib and numpy. Is there a way in matplotlib that an image you are plotting occupies the whole figure window.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get image im as nparray
# ........

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)
plt.set_cmap('hot')

plt.savefig("frame.png")
```

I want the image to maintain its aspect ratio and scale to the size of the figure ... so when I do savefig it exactly the same size as the input figure, and it is completely covered by the image.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042192/reduce-left-and-right-margins-in-matplotlib-plot

Comment: none of these answers fill the figure, but the answer here does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535393/matplotlib-getting-subplots-to-fill-figure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this using the following snippet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

delta = 0.025
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = Z2-Z1  # difference of Gaussians
ax = Axes(plt.gcf(),[0,0,1,1],yticks=[],xticks=[],frame_on=False)
plt.gcf().delaxes(plt.gca())
plt.gcf().add_axes(ax)
im = plt.imshow(Z, cmap=cm.gray)

plt.show()
```

Note the grey border on the sides is related to the aspect rario of the Axes which is altered by setting `aspect='equal'`, or `aspect='auto'` or your ratio.

Also as mentioned by Zhenya in the comments [Similar StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042192/reduce-left-and-right-margins-in-matplotlib-plot)
mentions the parameters to `savefig` of `bbox_inches='tight'` and  `pad_inches=-1` or p`ad_inches=0`

Comment: Plus one for `bbox_inches = 'tight'` which really answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like the one below.
It calculates the needed size for the figure (in inches) according to the resolution in dpi you want.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_im(image, dpi=80):
    px,py = image.shape # depending of your matplotlib.rc you may 
    #                          have to use py,px instead
    #px,py = image[:,:,0].shape # if image has a (x,y,z) shape 
    size = (py/float(dpi), px/float(dpi)) # note the np.float()

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=size, dpi=dpi)
    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    # Customize the axis
    # remove top and right spines
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
    # turn off ticks
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
    ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

    ax.imshow(image)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal object-oriented solution:

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False, xticks=[], yticks=[])
```

Testing it out with

```
ax.imshow([[0]])
fig.savefig('test.png')
```

saves out a uniform purple block.

edit: As @duhaime points out below, this requires the figure to have the same aspect as the axes.

If you'd like the axes to resize to the figure, add `aspect='auto'` to `imshow`.

If you'd like the figure to resize to be resized to the axes, add

```
from matplotlib import tight_bbox
bbox = fig.get_tightbbox(fig.canvas.get_renderer())
tight_bbox.adjust_bbox(fig, bbox, fig.canvas.fixed_dpi)
```

after the `imshow` call. This is the important bit of [matplotlib's tight_layout functionality](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/tight_bbox.py) which is implicitly called by things like Jupyter's renderer.

Comment: This only works for square images. Try `figsize=(2, 8)`

Comment: Added a fix for that.