# Matplotlib affecting tkinter window size and process behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, axes

From a more complex example, i distilled this minimal example:

```
from tkinter import Frame, Tk

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        plt.figure() # this makes the window smaller


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `plt.figure()` makes the window smaller and the process not end when I click the X on the top right. I really don't understand how a matplotlib command could cause this behaviour. A `plt.close()` allows me to kill the process by closing the window, but doesn't solve the size problem, and starts up the window behind other open windows.

Comment: To make the axes fill the figure (no padding), you need to set the axes position: `ax.set_position([0, 0, 1, 1])`.  Don’t use subplotpars at all.  Once you have the figure looking how you want, then work on the embedding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535393/matplotlib-getting-subplots-to-fill-figure

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem with the GUI

Comment: Well you are asking too many questions at once.

Comment: My question is just one: my gui shrinks in size when I use the generate_voronoi function instead of the dummy np.random, despite both returning numpy arrays, why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using `plt.Figure()` instead. Also `plt.savefig()` poses this problem, so if anyone reading this has this same issue, you can try:

```
fig = plt.Figure()
# work on figure...
fig.savefig("file.png")
```