# How to remove space only at the top of the plot - matplotlib

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I've seen many posts and answers online trying to answer this question.
However using `bbox_inches = 'tight'` the legend disappears.

This is one of my figures:
[image]

Since I have the legend outside the plot frame, I would like to remove only the top and bottom white space.

Anyone knows how to remove at least the top white space?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using `subplots_adjust()`? See, for example, the answer of @DaveP to this question: [Reduce left and right margins in matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042192/reduce-left-and-right-margins-in-matplotlib-plot)

Also, look at the answer by @Tian Chu to the same question.

EDIT: This works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot([1,2,3],[5,6,7],'gs-')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.99, right=0.99)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen this answer but perhaps I've used wrong values (they were smaller than those provide in the answer) because half of my plot dissapeared. I'll try again and let you know

Comment: @pavid: there's a possible gotcha mentioned in the comment by @drootang: the arguments of `subplots_adjust` are the values assigned to parameters: to have the top margin of `5%` of the figure size use `top=0.95` etc

Comment: Then join me in upvoting that answer and that comment :-)

Comment: Yes, I already vote in your comment :) I will accept the answer as soon as I try it! :)

Comment: I don't really understand how this work. I've tried `fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)` but it seems the white space at top is even increasing, at least not decreasing..

Comment: Can you try (a trivial) snipped from the edited post? It works as expected on my system, does it work on yours?

Comment: it works! Though I don't really understand this `ax.plot([1,2,3],[5,6,7],'gs-')` but gives me the correct output

Comment: Glad that it worked. As far as `ax.plot` is concerned, see here: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/faq/usage_faq.html

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't use the `bbox_inches = 'tight'` feature, since it doesn't work very reliably, as you already found out. I'd rather produce a PDF with bounds and then crop them using external tools. To do this seamless from python, I use

```
os.system('pdfcrop %s %s &> /dev/null &'%(pdf_in, pdf_out))
```

Here, `pdf_in` is the PDF you produced from matplotlib and `pdf_out` will be your final result.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to achieve this with an image? I'm trying to produce automatic images..

Comment: What do you mean by 'image'? A pixel based format? The strategy of course works with any format as long as you have an external program doing the cropping. www.imagemagick.org might help with that...

Comment: @pavid In addition to pdfcrop for pdf's, cropping a PNG is as simple as convert -trim FOO.png using imagemagick. This can be worked in an "automatic" way using a os.system call if you like.