# How to remove gaps between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

The code below produces gaps between the subplots.  How do I remove the gaps between the subplots and make the image a tight grid?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(16):
    i = i + 1
    ax1 = plt.subplot(4, 4, i)
    plt.axis('on')
    ax1.set_xticklabels([])
    ax1.set_yticklabels([])
    ax1.set_aspect('equal')
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=None, hspace=None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: post a link and it can be edited in.  `None` is not doing what you think, it means 'use the default'.

Comment: I tried adding numbers instead of 'None' but this didn't solve the prolem.

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)` would solve your problem, were it not for the fact that you use `'equal'` aspect. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html) to control the spacing between axes. There's more [information](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

plt.figure(figsize = (4,4))
gs1 = gridspec.GridSpec(4, 4)
gs1.update(wspace=0.025, hspace=0.05) # set the spacing between axes. 

for i in range(16):
   # i = i + 1 # grid spec indexes from 0
    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[i])
    plt.axis('on')
    ax1.set_xticklabels([])
    ax1.set_yticklabels([])
    ax1.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

[image: axes very close together]

Comment: Its not limited to `GridSpec`, if you grab the figure at creation you can also set the distances with: `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=, wspace=)`

Comment: what does the last line in the `for` loop mean to be ?

Comment: This is a very nice tip, but it does not use `subplots`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36049914/2980080) gets the job done without sacrificing `subplots`.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the horizontal spacing **only** between the first and second rows of axes?

Comment: @Stefano yes, you can use the solution by Rutger Kassies in the comments and just set the `hspace` to zero.

Comment: More info link outdated.

Answer (score 251):

The problem is the use of `aspect='equal'`, which prevents the subplots from stretching to an arbitrary aspect ratio and filling up all the empty space.

Normally, this would work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = [plt.subplot(2,2,i+1) for i in range(4)]

for a in ax:
    a.set_xticklabels([])
    a.set_yticklabels([])

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

The result is this:

[image]

However, with `aspect='equal'`, as in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = [plt.subplot(2,2,i+1) for i in range(4)]

for a in ax:
    a.set_xticklabels([])
    a.set_yticklabels([])
    a.set_aspect('equal')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

This is what we get:

[image]

The difference in this second case is that you've forced the x- and y-axes to have the same number of units/pixel. Since the axes go from 0 to 1 by default (i.e., before you plot anything), using `aspect='equal'` forces each axis to be a square. Since the figure is not a square, pyplot adds in extra spacing between the axes horizontally.

To get around this problem, you can set your figure to have the correct aspect ratio. We're going to use the object-oriented pyplot interface here, which I consider to be superior in general:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8)) # Notice the equal aspect ratio
ax = [fig.add_subplot(2,2,i+1) for i in range(4)]

for a in ax:
    a.set_xticklabels([])
    a.set_yticklabels([])
    a.set_aspect('equal')

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: I tried this but it still get a vertical gap between each column of images.. and set_aspect('equal') doesn't change anything for me

Comment: If you just need a raster graphic, you can open it in Gimp and Use *Image* → *Zealous Crop*. However, I did this for switched off axes `a.axis('off')`. Otherwise the ticks can be in the way.

Answer (score 75):

Without resorting [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/api/gridspec_api.html) entirely, the following might also be used to remove the gaps by setting *wspace* and *hspace* to zero:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()
f, axarr = plt.subplots(4, 4, gridspec_kw = {'wspace':0, 'hspace':0})

for ax in axarr.flatten():
    ax.grid('on', linestyle='--')
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Resulting in:

[image: .]

Answer (score 17):

With recent matplotlib versions you might want to try [Constrained Layout](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html). This does (or at least did) not work with `plt.subplot()` however, so you need to use `plt.subplots()` instead:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 4, constrained_layout=True)
```

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried `plt.tight_layout()`?

with `plt.tight_layout()`
[image]
without it:
[image]

Or: something like this (use `add_axes`)

```
left=[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7]
width=[0.2,0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
rectLS=[]
for x in left:
   for y in left:
       rectLS.append([x, y, 0.2, 0.2])
axLS=[]
fig=plt.figure()
axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[0]))
for i in [1,2,3]:
     axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[i],sharey=axLS[-1]))    
axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[4]))
for i in [1,2,3]:
     axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[i+4],sharex=axLS[i],sharey=axLS[-1]))
axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[8]))
for i in [5,6,7]:
     axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[i+4],sharex=axLS[i],sharey=axLS[-1]))     
axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[12]))
for i in [9,10,11]:
     axLS.append(fig.add_axes(rectLS[i+4],sharex=axLS[i],sharey=axLS[-1]))
```

If you don't need to share axes, then simply `axLS=map(fig.add_axes, rectLS)`
[image]

Comment: I tried tight layout, but it didn't get rid of the gaps, which is what I want.  The gridspec solution worked.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: This worked great in conjunction with the other suggestions.  tight_layout() helped remove the white space above and to the sides of the plot that served no purpose.

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` also worked in my case, but I had to pass a negative value to the `h_pad` parameter, as in: `plt.tight_layout(h_pad=some_negative_value)`. This is the only thing that worked for getting rid of this unexplainable gap between my two rows of subplots.

Answer (score 8):

Another method is to use the `pad` keyword from `plt.subplots_adjust()`, which also accepts negative values:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = [plt.subplot(2,2,i+1) for i in range(4)]

for a in ax:
    a.set_xticklabels([])
    a.set_yticklabels([])

plt.subplots_adjust(pad=-5.0)
```

Additionally, to remove the white at the outer fringe of all subplots (i.e. the canvas), always save with `plt.savefig(fname, bbox_inches="tight")`.

Comment: It will return this: TypeError: subplots_adjust() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pad'

Comment: Yeah, apparently the keyword has been dropped during summer 2021

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib will check the "subplotpars" param to define subplot positions. So this should work:

```
left   = 0.03 #The position of the left edge of the subplots, as a fraction of the figure width.
bottom = 0.05 #The position of the bottom edge of the subplots, as a fraction of the figure height.
right  = 0.99 #The position of the right edge of the subplots, as a fraction of the figure width.
top    = 0.97 #The position of the top edge of the subplots, as a fraction of the figure height.
wspace = None #The width of the padding between subplots, as a fraction of the average Axes width.
hspace = None #The height of the padding between subplots, as a fraction of the average Axes height.

fig.subplotpars.update(left, bottom, right, top, wspace, hspace)
```

You may adjust the parameters above individually(between 0 and 1) for your needs.