# Python plot 3 variables data on same axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, oscilloscope

We conduct experiments, our oscilloscope gives all plots on same screen though each variables is different in magnitude. Is it possible to achive same in the python using the experimental data?

My present code and output:

```
import random 

x = [i for i in range(1,11,1)]
y1 = random.sample(range(100, 1000), 10)
y2 = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)

plt.plot(x,y1,'-r')
plt.plot(x,y2,'-g')
plt.legend(['y1','y2'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty simple solution to that just use subplots

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [i for i in range(1,11,1)]
y1 = random.sample(range(100, 1000), 10)
y2 = random.sample(range(0, 10), 10)

ax1 = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(x,y1,'-r')
ax2 = plt.subplot(212,sharex=ax1)
plt.plot(x,y2,'-g')
ax1.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax1, ax2)
#make x axis on upper invisible
plt.setp(ax1.get_xaxis(), visible=False)

ax1.legend(['y1'])
ax2.legend(['y2'])
plt.show()
```

Looks like this
[image]

You can remove the bottom-border from the upper subplot and the upper border from the lower subplot with this:

```
ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
```

GridSpec might help you to remove margins, however I gues there should be a simpler way to remove the distance between two subplots

Comment: This looks good. Is it not possible to get plots as in the experiments?

Comment: Judging from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057260/how-to-remove-gaps-between-subplots-in-matplotlib) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42850225/eliminate-white-space-between-subplots-in-a-matplotlib-figure) you might want to something with `gridspec` to remove the white margin between the subplots

Comment: Also updated my answer to also include options to remove the border between the two subplots

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)` or a small value should help with the margins. https://i.imgur.com/3pyhskI.png

Comment: @Guimoute `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)` really made good impression by removing white spaces. It looks close to a real plot. Thanks a ton.

Comment: how to get grid x,y axis grid lines for all axes?

Comment: `plt.axis('off')` but then there are no axis at all, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces)