# matplotlib, imshow not having witespace between axes in grid plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridview, grid, imshow

I want a grid figure with m rows and n columns to be displayed sharing both x and y axis between subplots, and no whitespace between them. This is easy to achieve with simple plot in matplotlib, as with this code

```
def plot_me():
    n = 4
    m = 5
    f, axs = plt.subplots(m,n, sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0, wspace=0))
    x = np.arange(44)
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            axs[i,j].plot(np.sin(x*(i*j+1)))
```

[image]

but when I change `axs[i,j].plot()` to `axs[i,j].imshow()` then there is a vertical whitespace between the columns, but not a horizontal one! Why is that?

```
def imshow_me():
    n = 4
    m = 5
    f, axs = plt.subplots(m,n, sharex=True, sharey=True, gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0, wspace=0))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            axs[i, j].imshow(np.random.random((100, 100)))
```

[image]

I also tried with `f.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)` but with the same result.
And also with mosaic plot, and again in one axis there is no whitespace, while in the other is.

I'm using Python 3.11.2 in visual studio code 1.78.2, matplotlib 3.7.1

Thanks in advance.

EDIT, as with @jared linked thread [Matplotlib adjust image subplots hspace and wspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661906/matplotlib-adjust-image-subplots-hspace-and-wspace) does not raise the specific issue of `imshow` compared to simple `plot`, nor are the answerd there satisfactory solving the issue.

What solved the issue for me is using `pcolormesh`, as per @jared comment. Alternatively, as explained by @gboffi one can force the plot h/w ratio to be *exactly* 1.5 to avoid whitespaces

Comment: Are you set on using `imshow`? If it's not an image, use `pcolormesh`.

Comment: ```pcolormesh``` does the trick! Thanks!!
still it does not answer the question why ```imshow``` behaves that way, but i can work form here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib adjust image subplots hspace and wspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661906/matplotlib-adjust-image-subplots-hspace-and-wspace)

Comment: Re the question _"Why `imshow` behaves that way?"_, I have posted an answer below.

Comment: @jared thanks for spotting that thread, but it does not satisfactorily address the issue for a bigger than 2x2 grid, as  @Arcturus_B comments point out.

I think your ```pcolormesh``` suggestion, together with @gboffi is good to answer the question and solves the issue, at least partially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`imshow` is for images, and images *usually* are represented in terms of SQUARE pixels.

If an image is 200 px wide and 300 px high, Matplotlib places, let's say, on the screen a rectangle with an aspect ratio of 1.5 (the actual pixel count not being 200x300), and later draws the axes frame, complete with spines, labels etc, fitting the displayed image or, in your case, just the frame.

If so it happens that the aspect ratio (h/w) of the subplots is exactly 1.5, and I mean **exactly** 1.5 after the figure size, the axes ticks, the tick labels, the titles, etc are taken into account, then everything fits, otherwise...

Ultimately, the unwanted white space is added horizontally if the `figsize` is *too wide* or horizontally if the `figsize` is *too tall*, as shown in the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mat = [[i for i in range(j, j+10)] for j in range(10)]
fig0, axs0 = plt.subplots(2, 2, edgecolor='k', linewidth=1,
    figsize=(6,2), gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0, wspace=0))
for ax in axs0.flatten(): ax.imshow(mat)
fig1, axs1 = plt.subplots(2, 2, edgecolor='k', linewidth=1,
    figsize=(4,6), gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0, wspace=0))
for ax in axs1.flatten(): ax.imshow(mat)
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

---

**PS** In a comment [Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12131013/jared) correctly [suggested the use of `pcolormesh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76535588/matplotlib-imshow-not-having-witespace-between-axes-in-grid-plot/76538753#comment134945340_76535588). `pcolormesh` has a different approach and treats the not-an-image as *stretchable*, hence it can make it fit inside the elements of the grid.

---

**PS2** In other words, when you use `imshow` matplotlib fits the subplot *around* a fixed shape image, when you use `pcolormesh` Matplotlib distorts the image to fit *inside* a fixed shape subplot.

Comment: oks, thanks for knowing the machinery behind ```imshow```, curious to know that the "h/w" ratio has to be  *exactly* 1.5!!

Comment: @fffff Exactly 1.5 in my first example. In general, it depends.