# plot many figures in a FigureCanvasTkAgg object

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, padding

I am trying to plot many images in a figure and embed them into a frame, the problem is that when I use `plt.suplots`, the padding of the figures is to big, so the images is too small, I have tried using `aspect='auto'`, `tight_layout`, and manually change `figsize` but it does not work. here is my code

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=c, ncols=1, figsize=(10, 20))
for i in range(c):
    ax[i].imshow(layer_output[:,:,i].reshape(m, n, 1), cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=1, aspect='auto')
    ax[i].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax[i].axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax[i].set_title(str(i), fontsize=6)
    print(name + '[{}]: done'.format(i))
fig.set_facecolor('white')
fig.tight_layout()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)  
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
```

and the result:

[image]

When I plot an image in a figure and use `tight_layout`, it works, but the figure just includes one image. I want to use a figure for each image, but I don't know how to  plot many figures in a `FigureCanvasTkAgg` object, How could I do that or if you have any another way to solve the padding problem, please tell me that way

This is what I want:

[image]

The padding of the figures is not too big, its width fits the width of the frame

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example? What are the values for `m`, `n`, and `c`?

Comment: @TheLizzard c is the number of images, m and n are the dimensions of images, What I want is updated in my question

Comment: Please see [How to plot images in subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67595781/7758804). It may help with plotting the images in subplots, but I don't know about the Tkinter aspect.