# How do I add titles and get rid of the axis with just plt.figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add titles to each of the subplots and get rid of the x-axis and y-axis in them.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6)) # specifying the overall grid size

for i in range(16):
    plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)    # the number of images in the grid is 6*6 (16)
    img = mpimg.imread(f'../input/cifar10-mu/train_images/{train["filename"][i]}')
    plt.imshow(img)
    
fig.suptitle('Sample Images')
plt.show()
```

Here is the output of the code above

[image]

Comment: Replacing "plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)" with "plt.subplot(4, 4, i + 1, xticks = [], yticks = [], frameon = False)" should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot images in subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67595781/7758804) and [How to remove or hide y-axis ticklabels from a matplotlib / seaborn plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63756623/7758804)

Answer (score 0):

you can add these two lines:

```
plt.text(0, 0, f'Label {train["label"][i]}')
plt.axis('off')
```

so that the whole code will look like this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6)) # specifying the overall grid size

for i in range(16):
    plt.subplot(4,4,i+1)    # the number of images in the grid is 6*6 (16)
    img = mpimg.imread(f'../input/cifar10-mu/train_images/{train["filename"][i]}')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.text(0, 0, f'Label {train["label"][i]}')
    plt.axis('off')
    
fig.suptitle('Sample Images')
plt.show()
```