# How to eliminate whitespace between an image and a line plot? Setting 'hspace' to 0 doesn't do it

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, imshow

So I'm trying to get an intensity plot and an image of a spectrum snapped together in Matplotlib. But it just won't work. I tried most thing suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057260/how-to-remove-gaps-between-subplots-in-matplotlib) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces) question, but those are for the same kind of subplots, and none made the gap disappear. The one I used in my code, setting the keyword argument `gridspec_kw = {'wspace':0, 'hspace':0}` in `plt.subplots()` seemed to be the most reasonable to me, but it fails too. How should I eliminate all whitespace between the image and the plot?

My Matplotlib version is `2.2.2`.

Code:

```
impath = "Picture349.jpg" #a pic from the spectroscope
image = Image.open("Picture349.jpg")
imx, imy = image.size
imarray = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(image)

fig, (axint, axim) = plt.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw = {'wspace':0, 'hspace':0}, sharex=True)

#get a single row of pixels from the middle of the image, extend and plot it
pixrownum = imy//2
colorcol = imarray[pixrownum]
rainbow = np.broadcast_to(colorcol, (100, *colorcol.shape))
axim.imshow(rainbow)
axim.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

#get and plot intensity
bw = image.convert("L")
xcoords = np.arange(imx)
bwarray = np.asarray(bw)
axint.plot(xcoords, bwarray[pixrownum], "b")
axint.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: plot by the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises because the aspect ratio of your image is set to "equal" by default in `plt.imshow()`. This is changing the layout of your subplots and interfering with the `hspace` parameter.

There are 2 options that you have. First you can set the aspect ratio of your image to "auto" and keep `hspace` at 0. However, if the aspect ratio is important, then you can manually adjust the hspace parameter by setting a negative value.

Using a simple example:

```
image = np.random.randint(0,20,(300,1300)) # fake data

# ====== Option 1 ======
fig, (axint, axim) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw = {'hspace':0})
axim.imshow(image, aspect="auto")

# ====== Option 2 ======
# fig, (axint, axim) = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw = {'hspace':-0.23})
# axim.imshow(image)

axim.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

axint.plot(np.arange(0,1300), np.random.randn(1300), "b")
axint.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Both methods give:

[image]

I think that option 1 is better if the aspect ratio is not important. Option 2 requires trial and error to find the right parameter for `hspace`. In addition, if you change the figure size by dragging the window, option 2 will not scale properly