# Annoying white space in bar chart (matplotlib, Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

It's probably a trivial question, but I am trying to plot a bar chart with matplotlib and with rotated text on the x axis.
The code I'm using is shown below:

```
fig = plt.figure()

x_labels_list = []

for i in range(0, pow(2, N)):
    x_labels_list.append(str(f(i)))  # The function f() converts i to a binary string

ax = plt.subplot(111)
width = 1.0
bins = map(lambda x: x-width, range(1,pow(2,N)+1))
ax.bar(bins, my_data, width=width)
ax.set_xticks(map(lambda x: x-width/2, range(1,pow(2,N)+1)))
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels_list, rotation=90, rotation_mode="anchor", ha="right")
```

It works perfectly, but I obtain an annoying white space on the right of the x axis, as shown by the red ellipse in the following picture:

[image]

Do you know how I can remove it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a working example which replicates the figure you're showing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try calling `plt.xlim()` with the number of bins, e.g.

```
plt.xlim([0,bins.size])
```

Here is an example:

```
#make some data
N = 22
data = np.random.randint(1,10,N)
bin = np.arange(N)  
width = 1

#plot it
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(bin, data, width, color='r')
plt.show()
```

No `plt.xlim()` output:

[image: no xlim]

Now plot it with `plt.xlim` using the number of bins to define the size:

```
#plot it
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(bin, data, width, color='r')
plt.xlim([0,bin.size])
plt.show()
```

Results it:

[image: with xlim]

There may be a better way, but this should work for you.

Comment: You can also use `plt.axis('tight')` to accomplish the same thing without having to worry about specifying the number of bins.  Also, if you'd prefer a bit of space at the edges, use `plt.margins(0.05, 0)` to pad the limits with 5% of the data range in the x-direction and 0% in the y-direction.

Comment: @Joe Kington: Yes, I have tried also your solution, and it works!