# Extra space around a matshow/imshow plot after scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot matshow with aspect ratio 1, but when I rely on the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965743/how-can-i-set-the-aspect-ratio-in-matplotlib) I get an extra space around the plot that I cannot get rid off. What is the solution?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)
a=np.random.randn(8,4)
plt.matshow(a)
plt.colorbar(shrink=.5)
ax=plt.gca()
forceAspect(ax,aspect=1)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 4, 1), np.arange(1, 5, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 8, 1), np.arange(1, 9, 1))
#plt.tight_layout()
#ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%1d'))
#ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(1, 6, 1))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I understand it, you want two things: 1. adjust the height of the colorbar to match the hight of the plot *and* change the size of the figure such that there is not too much empty space around it.
The first thing is relatively easy to achieve. For the second one I believe that you have to specify the figure size manually.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)

a=np.random.randn(8,4)
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5,4))
plt.matshow(a,fignum=1)
ax=plt.gca()
forceAspect(ax,aspect=1)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 4, 1), np.arange(1, 5, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 8, 1), np.arange(1, 9, 1))
cbar = plt.colorbar()
plt.draw()
pos_cbar = cbar.ax.get_position()
pos_ax = ax.get_position()
pos_cbar.y0 = pos_ax.y0
pos_cbar.y1 = pos_ax.y1
cbar.ax.set_position(pos_cbar)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't get rid of the extra space using `fig.set_size_inches` do you have any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. Found the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042192/reduce-left-and-right-margins-in-matplotlib-plot

Comment: Yes, I came across that problem too. That is why I've set the figure size upon creating it. Cool that you have found a better solution to that part!