# Matplotlib - How to strip extra whitespaces from a plot without needing to save it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, whitespace

I have made a plot, and I don't want extra whitespaces in my plot; the question is:

*How can I strip extra whitespaces from a plot?*

I know you can strip extra whitespaces from a plot when you save it; Then you just do this: `plt.savefig('file_name.png', bbox_inches='tight')`

But I can't find any similar arguments you can pass to `plt.plot()` to have no extra whitespaces. Is it possible to pass an argument to `plt.plot()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look here: [Reduce left and right margins in matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042192/reduce-left-and-right-margins-in-matplotlib-plot)

Couple of options you can use:

`plt.tight_layout()`

`plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=0.1)`

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

after the plot command

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way imho is to click on the button "configure subplots" and adjust the sliders because you see the result immediately. You could although call the `tight_layout()` function directly on plt bevor  `show()`