# Add external margins with constrained layout?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When generating a figure to save to a pdf file, I'd like to adjust the positioning of the figure relative to the edges of the page, for example to add an inch margin along all sides. As far as I can tell, the solutions to do this (for example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042192/reduce-left-and-right-margins-in-matplotlib-plot)) either:

1. don't work with `constrained_layout` mode -- applying `plt.subplots_adjust()` after creating the figure but prior to `fig.savefig()` messes up the constrained layout
2. don't actually quantitatively adjust the positioning of the figure -- adding `bbox_inches="tight"` or `pad=-1` don't seem to do anything meaningful

Is there a straightforward way to adjust external margins of a constrained layout figure?

For example:

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(11, 8.5))

page_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1, figure=fig)

# this doesn't appear to do anything with constrained_layout=True
page_grid.update(left=0.2, right=0.8, bottom=0.2, top=0.8)

top_row_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 3, subplot_spec=page_grid[0])
for i in range(3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(top_row_grid[:, i], aspect="equal")

n_bottom_row_plots = 10
qc_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, n_bottom_row_plots, subplot_spec=page_grid[1])
for i, metric in enumerate(range(n_bottom_row_plots)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(qc_grid[:, i])
    plt.plot(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))

fig.suptitle("my big label", fontweight="bold", fontsize="x-large", y=0.9)

# this ruins the constrained layout
# plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2,right=0.8, bottom=0.2, top=0.8)

fig.savefig("temp.png", facecolor="coral")
```

Yields the following (I'd like to see more coral around the edges!):

[image]

Comment: As of matpotlib 3.3.1, images saved with `constrained_layout=False` display the right margin correctly. What version are you using?

Comment: @r-beginners I'm running 3.2.2, but I have `constrained_layout=True`... what do you mean the right margin is displayed correctly?

Comment: The same width as the left margin is in the right margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the rectangle that the layout engine operates within. See the `rect` parameter for each engine at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/layout_engine_api.html.

It's unfortunately not a very friendly part of the API, especially because `TightLayoutEngine` and `ConstrainedLayoutEngine` have different semantics for `rect`: `TightLayoutEngine` uses `rect = (left, bottom, right, top)` and `ConstrainedLayoutEngine` uses `rect = (left, bottom, width, height)`.

```python
def set_margins(fig, margins):
    """Set figure margins as [left, right, top, bottom] in inches
    from the edges of the figure."""
    left,right,top,bottom = margins
    width, height = fig.get_size_inches()
    #convert to figure coordinates:
    left, right = left/width, 1-right/width
    bottom, top = bottom/height, 1-top/height
    #get the layout engine and convert to its desired format
    engine = fig.get_layout_engine()
    if isinstance(engine, matplotlib.layout_engine.TightLayoutEngine):
        rect = (left, bottom, right, top)
    elif isinstance(engine, matplotlib.layout_engine.ConstrainedLayoutEngine):
        rect = (left, bottom, right-left, top-bottom)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Cannot adjust margins of unsupported layout engine')
    #set and recompute the layout
    engine.set(rect=rect)
    engine.execute(fig)
```

With your example:

```python
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(11, 8.5))

page_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1, figure=fig)

#your margins were [0.2, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8] in figure coordinates
#which are 0.2*11 and 0.2*8.5 in inches from the edge
set_margins(fig,[0.2*11, 0.2*11, 0.2*8.5, 0.2*8.5])

top_row_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 3, subplot_spec=page_grid[0])
for i in range(3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(top_row_grid[:, i], aspect="equal")

n_bottom_row_plots = 10
qc_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, n_bottom_row_plots, subplot_spec=page_grid[1])
for i, metric in enumerate(range(n_bottom_row_plots)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(qc_grid[:, i])
    plt.plot(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))

fig.suptitle("my big label", fontweight="bold", fontsize="x-large", y=0.9)

fig.savefig("temp.png", facecolor="coral")
```

Note: `fig.suptitle` text is apparently not handled by the layout engine, so it doesn't move.

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the constrained layout padding option?

```
fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad=4./72., h_pad=4./72.,
            hspace=0./72., wspace=0./72.)
```

While this might help with spacing, the constrained layout will restrict the amount of object that you can add to the defined space.

```
''' Here is the modified code '''

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(11, 8.5))
fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad=2./12., h_pad=4./12.,
            hspace=0., wspace=0.)
page_grid = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1, figure=fig)

fig.suptitle("My BIG Label", fontweight="bold", fontsize="x-large", y=0.98)


# this doesn't appear to do anything with constrained_layout=True
page_grid.update(left=0.2, right=0.8, bottom=0.2, top=0.8)

top_row_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 3, subplot_spec=page_grid[0])
for i in range(3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(top_row_grid[:, i], aspect="equal")

n_bottom_row_plots = 10
qc_grid = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, n_bottom_row_plots, subplot_spec=page_grid[1])
for i, metric in enumerate(range(n_bottom_row_plots)):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(qc_grid[:, i])
    plt.plot(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))


# this ruins the constrained layout
# plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2,right=0.8, bottom=0.2, top=0.8)

fig.savefig("temp.png", facecolor="coral")
```

Answer (score 3):

## To summarize the solutions for adding padding to constrained layout:

Thanks to @Samuel Powell
[Screenshot of layout before any corrections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGXXa.png)

**1. `plt.savefig(pad_inches)` (my favourite solution)**

Only visible in saved file.

```py
fig.savefig("temp.png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=1)
```

[image: Screenshot of layout with pad_inches]

**2. `set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad,h_pad)`**

Increases padding around the grid, but also spacing between subplots (makes each subplot smaller).

```py
fig.set_constrained_layout_pads(w_pad=0.8, h_pad=0.5, wspace=0, hspace=0)
```

[image: Screenshot of layout with w_pad and h_pad set]

**3. `layout_enginge.set(rect=(left, bottom, width, height)`**

The parameters refer to the Bounding Box of the grid. So `set(0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8)` places your subplot grid in the figure with 0.1 padding on each side (0.1 means 10% of the total figure size).

```py
engine = fig.get_layout_engine()
engine.set(rect=(0.5,0.1,0.8,0.8))
```

[image: Screenshot of layout with rect=(0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8)]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve more flexibility, I personally dont recommend using constrained layout and specifying [`left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`] together. Either specify the margin by yourself, or let matplotlib contrained layout do the rearangement for you. For more space between axes for placing texts and labels, just use `hspace` and `wspace` to adjust.

If I want more margin from both sides, and have enough space for axes labels, tick labels, and some texts. I do the following way.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8.5), facecolor='coral')
# you code already has this
left, right, bottom, top = [0.1, 0.95, 0.1, 0.5]
# You can specify wspace and hspace to hold axes labels and some other texts.
wspace = 0.25
hspace = 0.1

nrows=1
ncols=3
gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=1, ncols=3, left=left, right=right, bottom=0.6, 
top=0.9, wspace=wspace, hspace=hspace)
axes1 = [fig.add_subplot(gs1[row, col]) for row in range(nrows) for col in 
range(ncols)]

nrows=1
ncols=10
# this grid have larger wspace than gs1
gs2 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=1, ncols=ncols, left=left, right=right, 
bottom=0.1, top=top, wspace=0.6, hspace=hspace)
axes2 = [fig.add_subplot(gs2[row, col]) for row in range(nrows) for col in 
range(ncols)]
```

[image: Now, it have larger side margin as well as enough space betweeen axes]

Comment: Well, that works fine for this toy example... until you start adding things to the plot. Since you've turned off `constrained_layout`, I'm back in the mpl hell of tweaking every possible combination of label size and spacing.

Comment: The idea works for quite flexible layout. In the answer, I dont do anything to change label size. Even you use constrained layout, changing label size need addtional code unless you use your own default. You only need to change `wspace` and `hspace'. Constrained layout  means less flexibility af least from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is add a margin around the *finished* figure, and you are not concerned with how it looks on screen, another option is to set pad_inches with bbox_inches='tight'.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(11, 8.5))

fig.suptitle("My BIG Label", fontweight="bold", fontsize="x-large")

sfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 1)

# top subfigure
ax = sfigs[0].subplots(1, 3)

# bottom subfigure

n_bottom_row_plots = 10
axs = sfigs[1].subplots(1, n_bottom_row_plots)

fig.savefig("temp.png", facecolor="coral", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=1)
```

[image]

There are few things in the above comment and answers to note - first constrained layout indeed deals with subtitles, however, it doesn't if you manually set `y` because it assumes if you placed it manually that is where you would like it.

Second, there is a `rect` argument for the layout, but the suptitle doesn't get constrained by that, because `rect` is not really meant to be a constraint on decorations, but on where the axes get placed.  I think this could be considered a bug, or at least unexpected behaviour and constrained layout should work just inside its `rect`.  However, given the ease of adding padding in saved output it's probably not urgent, but if someone wants this to work that way, they are encouraged to open a bug report.

Finally, I modernized the above to use [subfigures](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html) which are meant to be easier to work with than nested subplotspecs.  Note each subfigure can *also* have a suptitle, etc